# How can I send and acquire an object from a connector in Mule Studio?

Tags: java, mule, mule-studio

I need to send and acquire a Java object to a custom connector that is expecting:

```
// inside MyConnector.java
@Processor
public Object doSomething(@Default(#[payload]) final Object data) {...}
```

I'm trying to send it an instance of the FakeData class.  I can verify this works when I send the object using Mule's FunctionalTestCase class:

```
<!-- inside mule-config.xml -->
<flow name="Do_Something">
    <myconnector:do-Something document-ref="#[payload]"/>
</flow>


public class FlowBuilder extends FunctionalTestCase {

    public void run() {
        Object payload = new FakeData();
        Flow flow = lookupFlowConstruct("Do_Something");
        MuleEvent event = FunctionalTestCase.getTestEvent(payload);
        MuleEvent responseEvent= flow.process(event);
    }
}
```

I can't figure out how to send a FakeData object and receive another object in a regular Mule flow using Mule Studio.

Can someone help me out?

------- Update --------

I am invoking the flow using an HTTP front end.  The flow looks like this:

```
[HTTP] -> [Java "My Transformer"] -> [Custom Connector]
```

I tried adding a transformer in front of the connector:

```
public class MyTransformer extends AbstractMessageTransformer {

    @Override
    public Object transformMessage(MuleMessage message, String outputEncoding)
            throws TransformerException {
        return new fakeData();
    }
}
```

Now I get this response:

```
Could not find a transformer to transform  
"SimpleDataType{type=org.mule.example.FakeData, mimeType='*/*'}" to 
"SimpleDataType{type=org.mule.api.transport.OutputHandler, mimeType='*/*'}". 
(org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerException) (org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerException). Message payload is of type: FakeData
```

Comment: Are you calling the "Do_Something" flow from another flow?  You need to have a flow somewhere that starts with an inbound-endpoint (e.g. http, jms, file) that then sets the payload to be a FakeData object before calling your connector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your flow, you can do something like:

```
<set-payload value="#[new org.mule.example.FakeData()]" />
```

EDIT: You've modified your question and added an HTTP inbound endpoint. The error you're getting is probably because you inbound HTTP endpoint is `request-response` and you haven't transformed `org.mule.example.FakeData` into something than be streamed over HTTP.

Comment: Hi David.  I get the following error when I try your suggestion:  "Execution of the expression "new FakeData()" failed. (org.mule.api.expression.ExpressionRuntimeException). Message payload is of type: String".

Comment: Stange. Is the `FakeData` declared in a package?

Comment: Wait from the edit you've make it's actually `org.mule.example.FakeData`.

Comment: Argl, you've modified your initial question :( I've extended my answer then.